# websphere-traditional image support java7?

Tags: java, docker, websphere, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to create the of Ibmcom/websphere-traditional with java7 support, how I can do this? When I run below it install with java8
FROM Ibmcom/websphere-traditional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said explicitly what version of Websphere you are trying to install.  You also haven't said clearly how you are installing it, though it looks like you are trying to install it as a docker container using IBM's published `ibmcom/websphere-traditional` docker image.

The [supporting documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/websphere-traditional/) for the `ibmcom/websphere-traditional` image currently says that it installs Websphere Application Server (WAS) 9.0.x.  (The actual `x` version number changes regularly.)

According to sources I have found, WAS 9.0 uses Java 8 by default.  [Some sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere_Application_Server#Version_9.0) say that WAS 9.0 can be configured to use Java 7, and [other sources](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/verify-java-sdk-version-shipped-ibm-websphere-application-server-fix-packs) say that Java 7 is not supported.  On balance, the former are probably wrong ...

Either way, the docker image you have downloaded appears to have only Java 8 support.  The source for the build is on [github](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker.websphere-traditional#docker-hub-image), and the Dockerfile says that the build does this:

```
/work/InstallationManagerKit/tools/imcl install \
    com.ibm.websphere.ILAN.v90 com.ibm.java.jdk.v8 \
    -acceptLicense -accessRights nonAdmin -showProgress \
    -installationDirectory /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer -repositories $REPO \
    -installFixes $IFIXES -sRD /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServerIMShared \
    -dataLocation /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServerIMData \
    -secureStorageFile /tmp/secureStore -masterPasswordFile /tmp/secureStorePwd \
    -preferences offering.service.repositories.areUsed=false,
```

That is saying to install WAS 9.0 and IBM Java 8 into the image.

There is no sign of support for Java 7 in the current versions of any of the Dockerfiles.

---

My suggestions would be:

1. Use Java 8 or later.  IBM have announced that their Java 7 product is end-of-life in July 2022.
2. If you really want (need) to use Java 7, the recommendation is to clone the github repository (https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker.websphere-traditional), modify the image build configs to select a different Java version and build your own docker image:

   - Checkout a branch or tag that corresponds to WAS 8.5.5 or earlier.
   - The comments in [issue #72](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker.websphere-traditional/issues/72) outline the things that you need to change.
   - Good luck!
3. I also came across [issue 141#](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker.websphere-traditional/issues/141) in which someone says that have built and shared some docker images.  (I'm not recommending this ...)

---

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I’ll try this but for issue#72 I see most of the answers has given directions to use links and those links are not working. Can you please help to share steps which I need to use to modify to use java7

Comment: WebSphere traditional 9 only runs on Java SE 8.

Comment: @Javahunger - No I can't.  If the instructions / suggestions don't work, I cannot help you build a custom docker image.  Have you tried contacting IBM WebSphere Support?

Comment: @Jarid - Are you saying that it only runs on Java 8, or is only supported on Java 8?

Comment: @Javahunger - actually, look at https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker.websphere-traditional/issues/141.  And from now on, could you please follow this up yourself; i.e. search the issues, etc for more leads.  It appears that have deliberately taken down the WAS docker images for older versions.  If you want to go down this route you *need* to be self-sufficient.

Comment: @StephenC It only runs on Java 8. WAS 8.5.5 allows a configurable Java runtime (it was built on 6, then later added support for 7 & 8), but WAS 9 is locked to Java 8.

Comment: @Jarid - I know it is not supported, but what do you mean by "locked"?  Does WAS 9.0 actively detect the Java version and refuse to run if it is launched on a Java 7 VM?   Does it simply not work; e.g. because of classfile version numbers, dependencies on Java 8 APIs, etc?

Comment: I guess "locked" is a strong word, as I don't think it goes out and checks the JVM version before launch, but I am pretty sure it's compiled against Java 8, so I'd be shocked if it works on a lower version.